# Python Json не видит массив

Tags: python, json

Делаю чекер для гифтов Discord
Проверяю видит ли python,
Но выскакивает ошибка
Код:

```
from urllib.request import urlopen
import json

url = "https://discordapp.com/api/v6/entitlements/gift-codes/1?with_application=false&with_subscription_plan=true"

with urlopen(url) as response:
            source = response.read()
data = json.loads(source)
print(data["message"])

s = input()
```

Ошибка:

```
raise HTTPError(req.full_url, code, msg, hdrs, fp)
urllib.error.HTTPError: HTTP Error 403: Forbidden
```

Comment: Не "Python Json не видит массив", а сервер ответил "запрещено", значит чего-то не хватает в запросе, например токена или другого способа авторизации.

Answer (score 2):

Для корректной работы `urlopen` требует передачи в заголовке запроса (headers) аттрибута `'User-Agent'` (например `'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64)'`) но так как сервер в данном запросе возвращает код `404` это вызывает исключение `HTTPError`.

Поэтому лучше воспользоваться `requests` который позволяет получить тело ответа:

```
import requests
import json

url = "https://discordapp.com/api/v6/entitlements/gift-codes/1?with_application=false&with_subscription_plan=true"
response = requests.request("GET", url)
data = json.loads(response.text)

print(data["message"]) # Unknown Gift Code
```